# How to make table format, repeat on each print page?

Tags: php, html, css

How to make repeat table on each page and sum of the column only shown on last page. I want to make something like this.

```
         PAGE I
---------------------------
| no | item        | qty  |
---------------------------
| 1  | Item 1      | 2    |
| 2  | Item 2      | 2    |
| 3  | Item 3      | 3    |
      .........
| 20 | Item 20     | 1    |
---------------------------
|    TOTAL         |      |
---------------------------

       PAGE 2
---------------------------
| no | item        | qty  |
---------------------------
| 21 | Item 21     | 2    |
| 22 | Item 22     | 2    |
| 23 | Item 23     | 3    |
      .........
| 40 | Item 40     | 1    |
---------------------------
|    TOTAL         | 50   |
---------------------------
```

As you can see, i need to show exact table design on each page and each page limit with 20 item only, and sum of the qty shown on last page.

this is i have been working on

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        @media print 
        {
            #printbtn {display: none;}
            thead { display: table-header-group; }
            tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
        }
        @media screen 
        {
            thead { display: block; }
            tfoot { display: block; position: fixed; }
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv(divID) {
                var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
                var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
                document.body.innerHTML = 
                  "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
                  divElements + "</body>";
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
            }
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="print" onclick="javascript:printDiv('tabel');">
    <div id="tabel">
    <table width="1200" border=0>
        <caption>table title and/or explanatory text</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>No.</td>
                <td>Headerrr</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>This is Footer</td>
                <td>this is footer too</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <?
            $x=1;
            for($x=1;$x<=500;$x++)
            {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?echo $x;?></td>
                    <td><?echo "Data ".$x;?></td>
                </tr>
                <?
            }
        ?>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is very important to my job. I really appreciate any suggest. Thank you.